# How to change the encoding of JSON dictionary string value?

Tags: python, json, encoding, diacritics, wikipedia-api

I ran into an issue a string encoded with "utf-8" doesn't print as expected. The string contains accented letters (á, é, ü, ñ, etc.), and is part of a JSON dict returned from Wikipedia API.

Below is an example with the letter é:

**== The complete code: ==**

```
import urllib
import json
import re

def check(wikitext):
    redirect_title = re.findall('\[\[[\S ]+\]\]', str(wikitext))[0]
    redirect_title = redirect_title.strip('[]')
    redirect_title = redirect_title.decode('ISO-8859-1').encode('utf8') 
    return redirect_title

serviceurl = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?'
action = 'parse'
formatjs = 'json'
prop = 'text|wikitext'
title = 'Jose Eduardo Agualusa'
url = serviceurl + urllib.urlencode({'action':action, 'page': title, 'format': formatjs, 'prop': prop})
uh = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = uh.read()
try: 
    js = json.loads(data)
except: 
    js = None
    print ' Page is not found'

wikitext = js["parse"]["wikitext"]
redirect_title = check(wikitext)
print 'redirect_title:',redirect_title

redirect_title2 = 'Jos\xe9 Eduardo Agualusa'
redirect_title2 = redirect_title2.decode('ISO-8859-1').encode('utf8')
print 'redirect_title2:', redirect_title2
```

The result is:

```
redirect_title: Jos\xe9 Eduardo Agualusa
redirect_title2: José Eduardo Agualusa
```

`redirect_title` is parsed from the Wikipedia API JSON. Before encoded, it prints as `'Jos\xe9 Eduardo Agualusa'`. After encoded, it doesn't seem to change.

`redirect_title2` is assigned directly with the string `'Jos\xe9 Eduardo Agualusa'` and then encoded.

Why do I get different results for `redirect_title` and `redirect_title2`? How can I make `redirect_title` print as `"José Eduardo Agualusa"`?

Comment: Looks to me like the json data from `uh.read()` has `'Jos\\xe9 Eduardo Agualusa'` in it, not `'Jos\xe9 Eduardo Agualusa'` — if you change `redirect_title2` to the former, the results match. Maybe it's an API bug.

Answer (score 0):

Your `check()` routine does some very odd things, including parsing the  string representation of a dictionary.

Try this instead:

```
def check(wikitext):
    for value in wikitext.values():
        result = re.findall(ur'\[\[.*?\]\]', value)
        if result:
            return result[0].strip(u'[]')
    return u''
```

Or this:

```
def check(wikitext):
    redirect_title = u''.join(wikitext.values())
    redirect_title = re.findall(u'\[\[[\S ]+\]\]', redirect_title)[0]
    redirect_title = redirect_title.strip(u'[]')
    return redirect_title
```